# Can we encrypt, a compressed java script file in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, compression, uglifier

I have created a compressed(.js) file by using "Uglifier" in rails production.rb file. However i needs to encrypt this compressed file.
Is there any gem or configuration to fulfill this task?

Nothing found any thing helpful.

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

Comment: did you checked [OpenSSL](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) library for encrypt/decrypt a file

Comment: Does it even make sense to encrypt an executable script file?